# how to compute histogram of silhouette?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, histogram, descriptor

I have read in a paper ([Human activity recognition with metric learning](http://vision.cs.uiuc.edu/projects/activity/papers/TranSorokinECCV08.pdf)) and trying to implement it.

the author used the channels (silhouette, optical flow), then after, he computed the histogram of each channel as shown in attached images.

I have computed the silhouette and optical flow of the video. but the question is,

1- what is the point of the mentioned histogram? is it for representing the features in a suitable form?

2- is this method as same as HOG.

3- how can I implement the mentioned histogram? is it just divide the bounding box? .. thanks so much.

[image]

[image]

sorry for an inconvenience

Regards

Comment: You are asking a question about a paper without naming the paper (let alone putting in a link) and then ask about an algorithm which is described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Kanade_method)?

Comment: I am not asking about the algorithm, I am asking about the benefit of the histogram that is used in different papers!

Comment: To get meaningful answers you might want to rephrase your question: What have you tried? What are your thoughts? Which papers are your referring to? Stackoverflow has a special section on [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: thanks for the response, I have made editing in the question and added a paragraph of the paper that showed the work of histogram.

Comment: Sorry, but without additional information (see my previous comments) this still is not a question which fits to this forum.

Comment: sorry for that, edited again and wish to be suitable now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer the various different questions, using pseudo-code for the latter.

1- The final aim of the authors seems to be to obtain a descriptor of the windows that they are *tracking* (I guess is tracking, I haven't read the paper). Thus, after computing silhouette `S` and `Fx` and `Fy` channels, the authors have a window of `MxMx3`, 3 channels by appending `[S, Fx, Fy]`. This is not a very suitable form of representing a window, because (1) is very high dimensional (`MxMx3` with possibly variable `M`), (2) is not scale or orientation invariant and (3) it is not a robust descriptor. The authors just use a histogram method (similar to the one in HoG but not the same) to convert the `MxMx3` channels to a 216-dimensional descriptor (`MxMx3 -> 216`, regardless of `M`).

2- The above kind of answers it. Is not HoG, but is similar to HoG, SIFT and other feature extraction methods.

3- If I didn't understand it wrong (with that few bit of information), just divide the bounding box in a 2x2 grid (4 squares/sub-windows). For each sub-window split it in 18 slices of 20 degrees (this is not straight forward, but knowing the position of a pixel respect to the centre of the sub-window, you can calculate the angle and therefore, the pie slice in which it falls.

Then, having the pixel `p` belonging to sub-window `(i,j)` (with `0 <= i,j < 2`) and the pie slice `k`, add its value (in each of the channels) to the histogram:

```
hist(i, j, k, c) += data(p, c)
```

where `c` is the channel (3 channels `[S, Fy, Fx]`) and `data(p, c)` is your 3-channel data at pixel `p` and channel `c`.

You will end up with a `2x2x18x3 = 216` descriptor. The extract that u provide doesn't mention anything about normalizing that descriptor, but I guess if it doesn't say anything, it would be just:

```
hist(i, j, k, c) /= sum(abs(flatten(hist)))
```

Or maybe normalizing each of the sub-windows and channels separately (as performed in hog):

```
hist(i, j, k, c) /= sum(abs(hist(i, j, :, c)) # summing over the 3rd axis `k`
```

Comment: thanks so much, the paper is for activity recognition ..he just mentioned about the normalization of bounding box but not about histogram. do you suggest any other descriptor that could shorten the dimension? thanks so much

Comment: @Mammo If you found the answer helpful, consider upvoting it! As for other descrptors, concatenation of HoG descriptors (for each of the channels) should work also fine, as in the paper "histogram of oriented gradients for human detection". Probably looking at the works that citate the one you mention you will find other used descriptors or features.